# Election or elections with the article

Tags: word-usage

Which form of the word "election" should I use?

"The  political ads before the election/the elections/elections/ election are annoying."

Comment: Are you referring to a particular election ('the election') or 'elections' in general?

Comment: The election that is held to vote for a president.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but do you mean the recent one or presidential elections in general? As I tried to indicate, if the first it's _the election_, if the second it's _elections_.

Comment: Oh, mean the recent one.

Comment: Can the article be omitted in both cases?

Comment: It would sound weird for in the case when you are trying to refer to one particular election.

Comment: I have told you twice that if you are referring to a particular election, such as the recent one, it's _the election_.

Comment: As Kate Bunting says, if the election is happening now, you need "The political ads before the election are annoying". If there's more than one election happening you need "before the elections". If the ads are *always* annoying (every time there is an election) you need "before elections". You can't say "before election" in this context.

Comment: I see now. Thank you. In what context would "before election" work?